# How can I prevent redundant values from being displayed in a column in an SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, duplicates

I have the Textbox in the data row set up in the usual way, with an expression like so:

```
=Fields!Description.Value
```

The data is being extracted and displayed fine, in fact too well for my tastes, as the Description is repeated N times; I want only the first unique value to display, and for it to be invisible after that until the Description changes. IOW, if it starts off with "Green Bay Packers" 80 times, I only want the first one to display that value, and the Description to not be visible again until its value changes to "Minnesota Vikings" (or whatever).

IOW, I want it to look like this:

```
Green Bay Packers    Aaron Rodgers
                     Clay Matthews
                     Julius Peppers
                     Eddie Lacey
```

...not like this:

```
Green Bay Packers    Aaron Rodgers
Green Bay Packers    Clay Matthews
Green Bay Packers    Julius Peppers
Green Bay Packers    Eddie Lacey
```

The TextBox does have a "HideDuplicates" property, but the accepted values are not the expected (by me) true and false; they are, instead, the following:

```
None
CPSData (the name of the data set the report uses)
Details
```

I can't see how choosing any of these would help me.

How can I effectively set "HideDuplicates" (or the appropriate property) to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HideDuplicates property is the way to do this. The options in the list are the scopes that are applicable within that section of the report. Choose one, and run the report in preview mode to see the results. If the results are not what you expect, try another option. It isn't terribly intuitive how it works, but it does work for me.

Comment: Cool; CPSData (the dataset used by the report) works; as you said, not very intuitive.